# Javascript - Extract html elements from json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I have my json returning html. Shown below is the ajax bit:

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: area.wrapper.attr('data-ajax'),
                data: data_submit,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function( data )
                {
                      console.log(data.content);
                } 
});
```

**console.log(data.content);** returns the html shown below:

```
<div class="gdlr-booking-room-wrapper" ><img src="" alt="" width="400" height="300" /></a></div><span class="gdlr-head">Start From</span><span class="gdlr-tail" id = "gdlr-currencyprice">$63.00 / Night</span></div><div class="clear"></div></div><div class="clear"></div></div></div>


<div class="gdlr-booking-room-wrapper" ><img src="" alt="" width="400" height="300" /></a></div><span class="gdlr-head">Start From</span><span class="gdlr-tail" id = "gdlr-currencyprice">$68.00 / Night</span></div><div class="clear"></div></div><div class="clear"></div></div></div>


<div class="gdlr-booking-room-wrapper" ><img src="" alt="" width="400" height="300" /></a></div><span class="gdlr-head">Start From</span><span class="gdlr-tail" id = "gdlr-currencyprice">$58.00 / Night</span></div><div class="clear"></div></div><div class="clear"></div></div></div>


<div class="gdlr-booking-room-wrapper" ><img src="" alt="" width="400" height="300" /></a></div><span class="gdlr-head">Start From</span><span class="gdlr-tail" id = "gdlr-currencyprice">$50.00 / Night</span></div><div class="clear"></div></div><div class="clear"></div></div></div>
```

From the above html response, i want to capture the prices that are under the class:

```
<span class="gdlr-tail" id = "gdlr-currencyprice">$63.00 / Night</span>
```

Now, the next step is should be retrieving the value from the class and this should be the way to go:

**$(".gdlr-tail").each(function(i) {}**

so to my question, how from my ajax response: **data.content**, should i capture my class attribute(gdlr-tail) to pass it to my iterating function to access my values? hope my question is clear

Comment: Why not just return *only* the HTML you actually need? Using JSON to wrap HTML is pretty redundant. Also the HTML you generate is invalid as you've repeated the same `id`; they need to be unique

Comment: The html is generated from a backend script that iterates hence the same id. Would be interested though on advice on how to return HTML that i ONLY need. thanks

Comment: You can iterate without using the same ID twice. If you need each element to have the same selector, use a class. Using an ID for this totally defeats the purpose of having an id.

Comment: As per Rory's suggestion you can just return the HTML as a string from your server side script & then put it in desirable parent or anything else.For this you will need to change the `dataType` attribute of your ajax to `html` instead of `json`

Comment: I get your point @techie_28 and that would work but apart from the html, there's more being returned from the response so it needs to remain as ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use RegExp to extract the values:

```js
var html = '<div class="gdlr-booking-room-wrapper" ><img src="" alt="" width="400" height="300" /></a></div><span class="gdlr-head">Start From</span><span class="gdlr-tail" id = "gdlr-currencyprice">$63.00 / Night</span></div><div class="clear"></div></div><div class="clear"></div></div></div><div class="gdlr-booking-room-wrapper" ><img src="" alt="" width="400" height="300" /></a></div><span class="gdlr-head">Start From</span><span class="gdlr-tail" id = "gdlr-currencyprice">$68.00 / Night</span></div><div class="clear"></div></div><div class="clear"></div></div></div><div class="gdlr-booking-room-wrapper" ><img src="" alt="" width="400" height="300" /></a></div><span class="gdlr-head">Start From</span><span class="gdlr-tail" id = "gdlr-currencyprice">$58.00 / Night</span></div><div class="clear"></div></div><div class="clear"></div></div></div><div class="gdlr-booking-room-wrapper" ><img src="" alt="" width="400" height="300" /></a></div><span class="gdlr-head">Start From</span><span class="gdlr-tail" id = "gdlr-currencyprice">$50.00 / Night</span></div><div class="clear"></div></div><div class="clear"></div></div></div>';

var result = html.match(/\$[\d\.]+ \/ [^<]+/gi);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Excellent. all the answers are technically right but this one hammers the point

Answer (score 3):

With jQuery, you could just do: $(data.content).find('.gdlr-tail').each(...)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(data.content)
    .find('.gdlr-tail')
        .each(function(i,el){
            alert(el);
         });
```